# WCF - same name tags in xml response

Tags: xml, wcf, rest, response

I am a newbie. Plzz help me at this.
In WCF rest application i want the following response

```
<parameterList>    
        <parameter>        
            <Question> Occupation </Question> 

            <Choice> Student/Others </Choice>      
            <Choice> Retired/housewife </Choice>       
            <Choice> Salaried/SelfEmployed </Choice>        
            <Choice> Doctor/CA/Socially Important Person </Choice> 

        </parameter>    
</parameterList>
```

I want 4 same "choice" tags with different contents. What i am getting is only the last "choice" tag.

#### IService.cs

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
UriTemplate = "/getQuestion")]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "parameterList")]
List<parameter> getQuestion();
```

#### Service.svc.cs

```
public List<parameter> getQuestion()
    {
        List<parameter> lstParameter = new List<parameter>();
        parameter param = new parameter();
        param.Question = " Occupation ";
        param.Choice = " Student/Others ";
        param.Choice = " Retired/housewife ";
        param.Choice = " Salaried/SelfEmployed ";
        param.Choice = " Doctor/CA/Socially Important Person ";
        lstParameter.Add(param);
        return lstParameter;
    }
```

#### parameter.cs

```
public class parameter
{
    public string Question
    {
        get{ } set{ }
    }

    public string Choice
    {
        get{ } set{ }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved It

```
        [XmlElement("Choice")]

        public List<string> Choice
        {
            get { return aChoice; }
            set { aChoice = value; }
        }
```

Just needed to add [XmlElement("")] above the property to rename the Xml Element.

Thanx james. u were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You keep overriding Choice with a new string. Your Choice property needs to be a List

```
   public List<string> Choice
        {
            get { return new List<string>();}
        }
```

then you can add to the list

```
param.Choice.add(" Occupation ");
param.Choice.add(" Retired/housewife ");
```

etc....

After that you would have to loop through all the choices and add them to you XML

Comment: Thanx for the reply.. After using your suggestion

I m getting

'<Choice>
     <string> Choice 1 </string>
     <string> Choice 2 </string>
     <string> Choice 2 </string>
     <string> Choice 2 </string>
</Choice>'
But i want

'<Choice> Choice 1 </Choice>
<Choice> Choice 2 </Choice>
<Choice> Choice 3 </Choice>
<Choice> Choice 4 </Choice>'
Plz help..