# What is the WCF C# equivalent of the following client XML?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

We have the following SOAP request in XML, which is sent to my web service.
I would like to parse multiple occurences of "Firstname", for instance into an array, but not necessarily.
Unfortunately I cannot change the request, only the web service.

What is the WCF C# equivalent of the following client XML?

```
<foo:NameHent>
    <foo1:Date>1988-03-05</foo1:Date>
    <foo1:Firstname>John</foo1:Firstname>
    <foo1:Firstname>Michael</foo1:Firstname>
    <foo1:Lastname>Doe</foo1:Lastname>
</foo:NameHent>
```

The following does not work:

```
public partial class NameHentParams
{
    private System.DateTime dateField;
    private string[] firstnameField;
    private string lastnameField;

    public System.DateTime Date
    {
        get { return this.dateField; }
        set { this.dateField = value; }
    }

    public string[] Firstname
    {
        get { return this.firstnameField; }
        set { this.firstnameField = value; }
    }

    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return this.lastnameField; }
        set { this.lastnameField = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677123/wcf-same-name-tags-in-xml-response

Comment: That's all? Where are namespace definitions (xmlns)?

Comment: @Sal Al Do you have a specific answer? I could not get it to work by simply changing string[] to List<string>

Comment: @Paweł Dyl The code is shortened to focus on the issue. For this issue, we can assume the namespaces are ok. The question is how to parse the Firstname tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml1 =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><foo:NameHent xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:foo1=\"http://sample.com\" xmlns:foo=\"http://example.com\"><foo1:Firstname>John</foo1:Firstname><foo1:Firstname>Michael</foo1:Firstname><foo1:Lastname>Doe</foo1:Lastname><foo1:Date>1988-03-05</foo1:Date></foo:NameHent>";

 XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NameHent));
        NameHent c = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml1)) as NameHent;


public class NameHent
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://sample.com")]
    public string [] Firstname;

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://sample.com")]
    public string Lastname;

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://sample.com")]
    public string Date;

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    public NameHent()
    {
        xmlns.Add("foo", "http://example.com");
        xmlns.Add("foo1", "http://sample.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what I should change in the code. The parsing is done 'automatically', and is triggered whenever an external client calls a specific method. I am also using ServiceContract, OperationContract and finally a MessageContract for the communication.

Comment: I have just create a WCF application and it seems to work as expect.

Comment: If you want me to send you the sample application let me know where you want me to send

Comment: I am only interested in the C# code that will match the SOAP request I have posted above. Is the WCF Client request exactly the same as the SOAP request?

Answer (score 0):

I am using WCF Test Client, but you could also test it using SOAPUI,

[image]

```
[ServiceContract]
public class NameHent
{
    [DataMember]
    public string[] Firstname;

    [DataMember]
    public string Lastname;

    [DataMember]
    public string Date;
}
```

Comment: Could you also include the SOAP Request and NameHent class in your answer, please?

Comment: I have added the NameHent class, the request is generated from by WCF Test Client

Comment: What is the proposed solution here? I tried removing getters and setters, but it does not make any difference.